# What size wire, breaker, and panel do I need for my shed?

Tags: circuit-breaker, grounding, subpanel

My shed is approximately 200ft from my main inside breaker panel in my house. Shed size is 20x20.

I want good lighting, approximately 8-10 120V plugs, and one 240V plug.

What size wire, size of inside breaker, and what size subpanel do I need?

Also how do I need to ground? I am reading I need a ground rod between the two panels and 2 ground rods at the shed, is this correct?

I am located in south - eastern United States. Alabama to be exact. Shed needs 240 plug for AC/heat window unit. I will most likely put a small refrigerator, and a mid-size television. Other than that will only be using 120 plugs for 1 power tool at a time.

Comment: 200 feet seems to be a quite popular number as a distance to a shed. Lots of questions (many linked under 'Related' to the right) on just how to do this.

Comment: What actual loads do you anticipate? Do you plan to have 8-10 120V power tools in use all at once, or just one or two at once? What size 240V load? Do you plan any heating or air conditioning?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as there's more detail now. Adam, if you put in just a bit more time formatting your post you're all good. Copy-paste dumps need a bit of polish to be readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From other questions like this, ~70amp feed/inside breaker(max 90 amp), 2-2-2-4 Al wire(best price), 200amp sub panel(just as cheap as smaller panels), ground between the two panels plus two ground rods at the shed.

Sub panel must have neutral and ground bus unbonded.

Main breaker of sub panel will replace needed disconnect.

Will need a load calculation to see how much power/amps you can spare for the shed.

Edit for question.  You want a ground path between the two panels, either a wire or metal conduit.  You do not need a ground rod between the two panels.

Comment: To add: if you haven't built the shed yet, when you pour the slab put in an Ufer ground.

Comment: Consider running the wire through conduit. You can get away with a shallower trench, the conduit helps protect it from critters, and if you _ever_ for any reason need to replace any wiring, you just pull the old out, pulling the new in behind it. No need to excavate a 2nd time.